# i want to understand whats wrong with my 3on1 function

Tags: python

```
def vencedor_linha(t):
    if (t[0]=='X' and t[1] and t[2]=='X') or (t[3]=='X' and t[4]=='X'  and t[5]=='X') or (t[6]=='X' and t[7]=='X' and t[8]=='X'):
        print("'X'")
        return True
    elif (t[0]=='O' and t[1] and t[2]=='O') or (t[3]=='O' and t[4]=='O'  and t[5]=='O') or (t[6]=='O' and t[7]=='O' and t[8]=='O'):
        print("'O'")
        return True
    else:
        return False

def vencedor_coluna(t):
    if (t[0]=='X' and t[3] and t[6]=='X') or (t[1]=='X' and t[4]=='X'  and t[7]=='X') or (t[2]=='X' and t[5]=='X' and t[8]=='X'):
        print("'X'")
        return True
    elif (t[0]=='O' and t[3] and t[6]=='O') or (t[1]=='X' and t[4]=='O'  and t[7]=='O') or (t[2]=='O' and t[5]=='O' and t[8]=='X'):
        print("'O'")
        return True
    else:
        return False

def vencedor_diagonal(t):   
   if (t[0]=='X' and t[4] and t[8]=='X') or (t[6]=='X' and t[4]=='X'  and t[2]=='X'):
        print("'X'")
        return True
   elif (t[0]=='O' and t[4] and t[8]=='O') or (t[6]=='X' and t[4]=='O'  and t[2]=='O'):
        print("'O'")
        return True
   else:
        return False

def determina_vencedor(t):
    if vencedor_coluna(t):
        return vencedor_coluna
    elif vencedor_linha(t):
        return vencedor_linha
    elif vencedor_diagonal(t):
        return vencedor_diagonal
    else:
        return False
```

So, if we use:

```
test1=('O',' ',' ',' ','O',' ',' ',' ','O')
```

and

```
test2=(' ',' ',' ','X',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ')
```

it should return me, `determina_vencedor(test1)` -> `'O'` and `determina_vencedor(test2)` -> `False`

All fine with `test2`, problem is it gives me `"'O', function vencedor_diagonal at 0x0000000002C29A48"` at test2.

Whats wrong?! Help me figure out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to return the *result* of your functions, not the functions themselves. Or rather, since all your functions return either `True` or `False`, you want to return `True` if the function returned `True`:

```
def determina_vencedor(t):
    if vencedor_coluna(t):
        return True

    if vencedor_linha(t)
        return True

    if vencedor_diagonal(t)
        return True

    return False
```

This can be combined into a loop:

```
def determina_vencedor(t):
    for func in (vencedor_coluna, vencedor_linha, vencedor_diagonal):
        if func(t):
            return True
    return False
```

or you can use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to test all functions:

```
def determina_vencedor(t):
    return any(f(t) for f in (vencedor_coluna, vencedor_linha, vencedor_diagonal))
```

Comment: it works! thanks so much, now i only have a problem. i want determina_vencedor(test1) to return 'O' and not 'O' and True

Comment: @wankinglemur: Your functions *print* `'O'`, they do not return it. In that case, return `'O'` *instead of `True`* and adjust your `determina_vencedor()` to return the return value of the first function that returns *something true*.

Comment: thanks so much, now i know a bit more of python cuz of u. thumbs up!